# Trying to open Modal window with click on classname instead of id

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

Hellow Everyone,

I believe I'm missing something very simple, but I can't seem to find it. 
I'm trying to open a modal window when the user clicks on a div. When the div has the **"id"** of **myBtn1**, it works. But when the div has the **"class"** of **myBtn1**, it doesn't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**This works**

```
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

<a href="http://www.cnn.com/" target="_blank">
<div id="myBtn1">Open Cnn</div>
</a>
```

**This doesn't work.**

```
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn1");

<a href="http://www.cnn.com/" target="_blank">
<div class="myBtn1">Open Cnn</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an `array-like object`. You need to get the first item from it via `index`.

If you notice, get`Element`ById is in a single form, but get`Elements`ByClassName is in the plural form

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("myBtn1")[0];

<a href="http://www.cnn.com/" target="_blank">
   <div class="myBtn1">Open Cnn</div>
</a>
```

Comment: that was it. Thank you @Suren Srapyan!